# WCF failing when service is impleneted over HTTP AND HTTPS

Tags: wcf

```
<system.serviceModel>
<services>
<service name="foo">
<endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="testbehaviour" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="testcontact" bindingConfiguration="webBinding" />
<endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="testbehaviour" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="testcontact" bindingConfiguration="webBindingHttps" />
</service>
</services>
<system.serviceModel>
```

As shown in the the web.config extract above, on our windows server 2008 machines, we had one endpoint that could be reached over HTTP and HTTPS.

I have just done an install of server 2012 (with iis8), and I now get the message 
"Could not find a base address that matches scheme https for the endpoint with binding WebHttpBinding. Registered base address schemes are [http]."

The very odd thing is - if I comment one `endpoint` element out (leaving just one active endpoint left), then the remaining endpoint will work fine?

Answer (score 0):

I had set the site up in IIS wrongly - I had created a separate website for the HTTP version and one for the HTTPS version, when infact they should be the same website, but with HTTPS and HTTP bindings